# Edit JBoss standalone.xml

Tags: jboss, cloudbees

Is it possible to edit the standalone.xml (and domain) of the deployed JBoss on cloudbees? For example if I wanted to disable rest and webservices modules due to a conflict with my deployed .war?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but as an alternative you can deploy your own customized container using [clickstack](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack), see [this sample](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/jboss71-clickstack) running jboss 7.1